# Incomplete type used in nested name specifier, despite linking

Tags: c++

When attempting to compile the source code below, I keep getting the error mentioned in the title, or more specifically:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Os ./t*.cpp ./libbrack.a
./test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
./test.cpp:4:35: error: incomplete type ‘brack::cpu::CharClassifier’ used in nested name specifier
    4 |   if (brack::cpu::CharClassifier::isLowercase('a')) {
      |
```

Code below.

```cpp
// bcpu.hpp
#ifndef BRACK_CPU_HPP
#define BRACK_CPU_HPP

namespace brack {
namespace cpu {
class CharClassifier;
}
} // namespace brack

#endif
```

```cpp
// bcpu.cpp
#define BRACK_CPU_CPP

#include "bcpu.hpp"

#include <array>

namespace brack {
namespace cpu {
class CharClassifier {
private:
  static constexpr std::array<std::array<bool, 5>, 127> S_lookupTable {
    []() constexpr {
      std::array<std::array<bool, 5>, 127> lookupTable{};

      // numerical characters
      for (char c = 48; c <= 57; c++) {
        lookupTable[c][0] = true;
      }

      // uppercase letters
      for (char c = 65; c <= 90; c++) {
        lookupTable[c][1] = true;
      }

      // lowercase letters
      for (char c = 97; c <= 122; c++) {
        lookupTable[c][1] = true;
      }

      // whitespace characters
      for (char c : {' ', '\t', '\v', '\f'}) {
        lookupTable[c][2] = true;
      }

      // newline character
      for (char c : {'\n', '\r'}) {
        lookupTable[c][3] = true;
      }

      lookupTable['\0'][4] = true;

      return lookupTable;
}()
};

public:
  constexpr CharClassifier() = default;
  ~CharClassifier() = default;

  static constexpr bool isNumerical(char c) noexcept {
    return S_lookupTable[c][0];
  }

  static constexpr bool isUppercase(char c) noexcept {
    return S_lookupTable[c][1];
  }

  static constexpr bool isLowercase(char c) noexcept {
    return S_lookupTable[c][1];
  }

  static constexpr bool isWhitespace(char c) noexcept {
    return S_lookupTable[c][2];
  }

  static constexpr bool isNewline(char c) noexcept {
    return S_lookupTable[c][3];
  }

  static constexpr bool isNull(char c) noexcept {
    return S_lookupTable[c][4];
  }
};
}
}
```

These are the header files included by the file that errors.

```cpp
#include "bcpu.hpp"

int main() {
  if (brack::cpu::CharClassifier::isLowercase('a')) {

  }
}
```

For now, my goal is to make a class that provides static methods for “classifying” a character (as in letter, digit, etc.), but I keep getting this nonsense error. I tried making my research, unsuccessfully doing so.

When I put the definitions into the header file, the errors are fixed, but I'm already linking the library.

Comment: Put the class definition in the header file. Only put the implementation of the member functions in the `.cpp` file

Comment: Is that the only viable solution? I purposefully linked it because of the advantages.

Comment: What advantages are those? You need _some_ member function(s) in the class definition for outside users to be able to use the class. You can hide some implementation details using the _pimpl_ idiom but unless you specify what you are really wanting from this, it's hard to say if that'd help

Comment: how would the compiler know how to call your method without having it's prototype ? that's the reason why methods are defined in the header

Comment: @laenNoCode I keep receiving error messages about me redefining the class.

Comment: Put the class definition in the header file _only_. Don't redefine the class in the cpp file. Only implement the member functions there

Comment: No, not if you get error messages about redefining the class. You are then putting the definition in more than one place

Comment: @PhoenixCausesOof, you should only add the method name and parameter (for instance ` static constexpr bool isNumerical(char c);`) and then you define in the .cpp the method using : `static constexpr bool CharClassifier::isNumerical(char c){/*your code*/}`

Comment: @IaenNoCode I did exactly that. The first problem was that I couldn't use static outside the class (easily fixed), then, it complained because it couldn't find the inline function (constexpr forces inline), so I removed the constexpr qualifier, which fixed the issues, but will probably reduce speed. Well, including headers recompile the source code, so I should've foreseen this. Thank you both for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be forced to either define the class in the header or sacrifice performance by omitting `constexpr`. This is because `constexpr` tells the compiler to resolve the expression at compile time, which would've not been possible without recompiling the header.